# Running Custom JAR on Amazon EMR gives file system error (error=2, No such file or directory)

Tags: java, bash, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-emr

I'm trying to setup a jupyterhub environment in AWS EMR. I've been following the instructions on the [documentation][1] without issue.

I now want to add a step during set up to add users. The documentation gives a snippet on how to do so.

> **Example: Bash script to add multiple users**
>
> The following sample bash script ties together the previous steps in
> this section to create multiple JupyterHub users. The script can be
> run directly on the master node, or it can be uploaded to Amazon S3
> and then run as a step.
>
> ```
> # Bulk add users to container and JupyterHub with temp password of username
> set -x
> USERS=(shirley diego ana richard li john mary anaya)
> TOKEN=$(sudo docker exec jupyterhub /opt/conda/bin/jupyterhub token jovyan | tail -1)
> for i in "${USERS[@]}"; 
> do 
>    sudo docker exec jupyterhub useradd -m -s /bin/bash -N $i
>    sudo docker exec jupyterhub bash -c "echo $i:$i | chpasswd"
>    curl -XPOST --silent -k https://$(hostname):9443/hub/api/users/$i \
>  -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN" | jq
> done
> ```
>
> Save the script to a location in Amazon S3 such as
> s3://mybucket/createjupyterusers.sh. Then you can use
> script-runner.jar to run it as a step.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-jupyterhub-pam-users.html

After following the procedure above I successfully launched the EMR cluster.

I now want to use my own script in place of the shell script above but I'm having issues running it.

I get the following error:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/tez/lib/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-23QLFU7JXPPM7/./add_users_ERM.sh" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory
    at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.scriptrunner.ProcessRunner.exec(ProcessRunner.java:143)
    at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.scriptrunner.ScriptRunner.main(ScriptRunner.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-23QLFU7JXPPM7/./add_users_ERM_Linuxx.sh" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.scriptrunner.ProcessRunner.exec(ProcessRunner.java:96)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 8 more
```

*Could some explain why running script-runner.jar to run my shell fails but works fine when using the shell in the tutorial?*

---

**add_users_ERM.sh for reference:**

```
#!/opt/conda/bin/python

import os
import subprocess
import traceback
import sys

TOKEN="$(sudo docker exec jupyterhub /opt/conda/bin/jupyterhub token jovyan | tail -1)"

def users_from_text(file):
        
    #Now we have users and their team, we can create a user account and assign them to a team
    for user in file:
                username = user
 
                print(f"Adding {user}")
                cmd = ["sudo", "docker", "exec", "jupyterhub","useradd", "-m" ,"-s" ,"/bin/bash" ,"-N" ,username]
                p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
                output, error = p.communicate()
                output = output.strip().decode("utf-8")
                error = error.decode("utf-8")
                if p.returncode != 0:
                    print(f"Error adding user: {error}")
                else:
                    print(F"{user} was added")

                cmd = ["sudo", "docker", "exec", "jupyterhub","bash", "-c" ,f"echo {username}:{username} | chpasswd"]
                p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
                output, error = p.communicate()
                output = output.strip().decode("utf-8")
                error = error.decode("utf-8")
                if p.returncode != 0:
                    print(f"Error adding password: {error}")
                else:
                    print(F"{user} password was added")

                cmd = ["curl", "-XPOST", "--silent", "-k",f"https://$(hostname):9443/hub/api/users/{username}", "-H" ,f"Authorization: token {TOKEN}", "|", "jq"]
                p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
                output, error = p.communicate()
                output = output.strip().decode("utf-8")
                error = error.decode("utf-8")
                if p.returncode != 0:
                    print(f"Error adding user to JH: {error}")
                else:
                    print(F"{user}  was added to JH")

                #To do: Convert api call to subprocess request
    return output
    


test_data = ["worker_1", "worker_2", "worker_3", "worker_4", "worker_5", "worker_6"]
txt_file = test_data  
print("Attempting add_user.sh script")
output = users_from_text(txt_file)
```